# how do i install PHP with JSON and OAuth on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: php, macos, osx-snow-leopard, dropbox

i want to use the dropbox api via this library

http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/

Comment: This likely belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters install MAMP (see google) is probably the easiest way for the server w. PHP, then run `pecl install oauth` in the Terminal and then you should be good to just download that library & use it.

Comment: ps i had to do sudo pecl install oauth